# How to get element from a scope json according value of another scope json in angular js?

Tags: json, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have two simple json scope variables.

I need to display a particular object's value from my first json according to another object value in my second json,

like:

{{json1.json2.id}}
The problem is angular thinks json2 is an object inside json1. I want the compiler to get the result of json2.id and store it to an object (say temp) and find corresponding object value in json1 (json1.temp).

This is the concept i am trying to implement.

i tried:
{{json1.[json2.id]}}

{{json1}}.{{json2.id}}

{{json1.(json2.id)}}

I hope someone can understand what i am trying to ask.

json sample

json1
previousExerciseCount: {
                1: 0,
                3: 3,
                6: 4,
                10: 3,
                11: 2,
                15: 2,
                18: 4,
                21: 1,
                23: 5,
                24: 1,
                25: 7
            }

json2
exerciseLogs: 
[{
                       id: 7,
  
                    name: "push",
  
                    reps: "0",
  
                    time: 1424177576006
                }, {
  
                    id: 15,
  
                    name: "jump",
  
                    reps: "N/A",
  
                    time: 1424177576002
                }, {
  
                    id: 23,
  
                    name: "pull",
  
                    reps: "0",
  
                    time: 1424177576001
                }, {
  
                    id: 40,
  
                    name: "cross",
  
                    reps: "4",
  
                    time: 1424177576000
                }]

I am iterating through json2 using ng-repeat
each iteration gives me 
exerciseLog : {
                    id: 40,
                    name: "cross",
                    reps: "0",
                    time: 1424177627130
                }

For example, i need to get the value of json.exercise.id
That is, when i get exerciseLog.id as 40, i need to get its corresponding previousExerciseCount.

Comment: add your sample json

Comment: yes add an example of json array and what you are trying to get..

Answer (score 0):

in your controller `$scope.result=$scope.json1[json2.id];`//JS code

and in the HTML  use `{{result}}` //HTML

Comment: I  am using this inside ng-repeat , i need to get each value of json1.json2.id.

//njan parayanath manasilayo?